# Make a partition with a rule

Tags: rule, partitions

I wrote this line of code :

```
{{1, 1, 1}, {1, 1}} /. ((x___ /; Length[x] > 2) -> Partition[x, 2, 1])
```

generates this error :

> Partition::pdep: Depth 1 requested in object with dimensions {}.

The questions are simple :
Is it possible to avoid this error ?
Are there any alternative ?

Thank you for your attention.

**Edit**

Thank you for your answers.
I did not realize the utility  of RuleDelayed up to now .

Comment: Please upvote answers that you found helpful and accept the the best answer (green tick).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{{1, 1, 1}, {1, 1}} /. 
   a : {__Integer} /; Length[a] > 2 :> Partition[a, 2, 1]
```

> {{{1, 1}, {1, 1}}, {1, 1}}

```
{{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 1}} /. 
    a : {__Integer} /; Length[a] > 2 :> Partition[a, 2, 1]
```

> {{{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}}, {1, 1}}

**Alternative**

Vectors of length `2` are not partitioned:

```
Partition[{1, 1}, 2, 1]
```

> {{1, 1}}

But observe the extra brackets. If they don't disturb you could more directly write:

```
res = Map[Partition[#, 2, 1] &, {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {8, 8}}]
```

> {{{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}}, {{8, 8}}}

If they disturb:

```
res /. {{a__}} :> {a}
```

> {{{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}}, {8, 8}}

This alternative should be faster with large lists.

Answer (score 3):

Use RuleDelayed instead of Rule

```
{{1, 1, 1}, {1, 1}} /. ((x___ /; Length[x] > 2) :> Partition[x, 2, 1])
```